# Perl Regex: Increment number after string in text file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line in a text file that says:

```
$cacheVersion_conference = '2';
```

I want to increment the number 2.

I think I got as far as matching `"$cacheVersion_conference = "` with:

```
[\n\r].*$cacheVersion_conference = \\s*([^\n\r]*)
```

This way, I could possibly match that and replace everything until the next line with the incremented number.

**UPDATE** - Answer for writing back onto the source file. Requires installing Path::Tiny

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny qw(path);

my $filename = 'my/source/file.php';

my $file = path($filename);

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "File open err: $!";

while (<$fh>) {  # read the file line by line
    if (/\$cacheVersion_conference = '(\d+)';/) { # match the line & capture the digit(s)
       my $new_ver = $1 + 1; # increment the digit
       my $line = <$fh>;
       chomp $line;

       my $replacement = "\$cacheVersion_conference = '$new_ver';\n"; 

       my $data = $file->slurp_utf8;
       $data =~ s/$line/$replacement/g;
       $file->spew_utf8( $data );

       print $replacement; # print newly constructed line 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would want to do is something like this:

```
open (my $IN, '<', 'yourFile.txt') or die ('IN File err: '. $!);
open (my $OUT, '>', 'newFile.txt') or die ('OUT file err: '. $!);

while (<$IN>) {  # read the file line by line
    if (/\$cacheVersion_conference = '(\d+)'/) { # match the line & capture the digit(s)
       my $new_ver = $1 + 1; # increment the digit
       print $OUT "\$cacheVersion_conference = '$new_ver';\n"; # print newly constructed line 
    }
    else {print $OUT} # print out the unmatched, unchanged lines
}
```

That might be a little easier to understand than an inline substitution

Comment: One thing that needs to be updated is the if statement missing the semicolon.

Comment: I didn't think about printing back to the file. I added some lines to print back to a new file.

Comment: Your semicolon is not important to the match. In fact, you could have left most of the line out of the matching criteria. Then you'll see patterns like: \s[^\s]{4,7}.+? etc. etc. - which are awesome in their power  - but, when I come back to the script later, I have to re-figure out what that super creative pattern was doing. I find it easier to use human readable text in the pattern whenever I can. All you really needed to do in that match was have enough in your pattern to match that unique line and capture the digits.

Comment: For some reason the semicolon gave me problems, generating a multitude of "$cacheVersion_conference =..." in my text file.

Comment: Not a huge issue, but is there a way of preventing it adding an additional new line when it saves the data to the text file? Every time I save, it makes an additional new line, so eventually it stacks up all this blank space.

Comment: You appear to be slurping the entire file into the var $data and doing a substitution on the slurped file then outputting it. No need to do any of that. Print the file back out line-by-line as you read it in. See my updated answer. (I don't know why that works at all)

Comment: I'm setting the same $IN and $OUT destination. Is that not okay? It deletes all the text in my file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142303/discussion-between-cbmckay-and-vagueexplanation).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have read an entire file into a scalar variable. The approach is inexplicably popular and makes tasks such as this a lot more awkward than they need to be while using up much more memory than necessary

Unless there is a good reason to have the whole file in memory at once you should read it a line at a time. If this is *all* you have to do to the file then it would look like this

```
open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    s/(\d+)/$1+1/e if /\$cacheVersion_conference/;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that you read line by line into a `$line` variable

```
$line =~ s/^\$cacheVersion_conference\s*=\s*\K'(\d+)'/ q(') . (1+$1) . q(') /e;
```

The [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) is a form of [lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), an *assertion* that the pattern that precedes it is indeed there. It also discards all previous matches, what allows `\K` to also handle variable length patterns.

The `/e` makes the replacement side be evaluated as code, and there we increment the number and reassemble the quoted number, `'N'`.  It's got to be legal code so literals need be quoted, `q(')`, we need to concatenate strings with `.` and with the expression in parenthesis, `(1+$1)`.

Alternatively, you can just capture it all and then reassemble the whole thing

```
$line =~ s/^(\$cacheVersion_conference\s*=\s*)'(\d+)'/$1.q(').(1+$2).q(')/e;
```

Comment: Note that you can put the `\K` after the first quote (and eventually use a lookahead for the second.)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Correct, however I thought it be clearer to have both quote marks handled in a consistent (same) way.

Comment: The alternative answer looks great, but I'm getting a syntax error "near unexpected token `('"

Comment: @VagueExplanation Both of these work for me as they are, copy-pasted from here (just tested again). It sounds like something didn't get copied when you try it?  (Is this a normal line in a normal Perl script?)

Comment: @VagueExplanation Those `'` won't work in a one-liner, if that's what is going on.  To get `'` in a one-liner a little more is needed.  One way is to use ascii for `'`, ie. `\047`